# Scala: Need advice on a better way to get properties from file

Tags: scala, file, properties

I would like suggestions on a better approach to accessing file properties within the application.

As the title suggests, using scala I have various config files with some properties, I would like to access those properties using some kind of an enum (or case object) without having to remember string literals.

Below is my current implementation, but I feel that it is more boiler plate than necessar due to my lack of knowledge.

File: database.conf

```
database {
    datasource {
        driverClassName  = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bamboozle"
    }
}
```

Case Object: DatabaseConfig

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

case object DatabaseConfig extends Enumeration
{
    val
    databaseConfigFile
    ,dataSourceClassName
    ,dataSourceURL = Value

    private val dbMap = Map[DatabaseConfig.Value, String](
        databaseConfigFile -> "database.conf",
        dataSourceClassName -> "database.datasource.driverClassName",
        dataSourceURL -> "database.datasource.url"
    )

    def get(property: DatabaseConfig.Value): String = ConfigFactory.load(dbMap(DatabaseConfig.databaseConfigFile)).getString(dbMap(property))
}
```

Access properties using
    println(DatabaseConfig.get(DatabaseConfig.dataSourceURL))

As you can see if I add values to database.conf I then need to update DatabaseConfig enums AND the dbMap. Are there better idiomatic ways to accomplish this. Searching for "scala reading file properties" mostly produces results where string literals are used -____-. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you could use PureConfig which builds on typesafe config and allows you to directly derive encoders for your case classes representing your config. https://pureconfig.github.io

Is something like that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.